# FactoryGirl has_many :through relationship broken in Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

Everything was working as expected, until I upgraded to Rails 3.2.11.

This is how my models are setup :

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :institutes
    has_many :teachers, :through => :institutes
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :institutes
    has_many :students, :through => :institutes
end

class Institute < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :teachers
    belongs_to :students
    validates :teacher_id, :presence => true
    validates :student_id, :uniqueness => {:scope  => :teacher_id}, :presence => true
end
```

My factories.rb file looks like this :

```
factory :student do
    first_name "abc"
    last_name "xyz"
    teachers {|t| [t.association(:teacher)] }
end

factory :teacher do
    first_name "ABC"
    last_name "XYZ"
end

factory :institute do
    association :student
    association :teacher
end
```

---

### **The Problem :**

When I do :

```
FactoryGirl.create(:student)
```

It gives me the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Institutes is invalid
```

It seems like, it creates `:teacher`, then `:institute` and finally `:student`. Therefore, it doesn't have the `student_id` when it creates `:institute`, making it invalid.

The weird thing is, the same model and factory_girl setup was working fine with Rails 3.2.8.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about somthing like this

```
factory :student do |student|  
  ...
  student.after_create do |student|  
    student.teachers << :teacher  
  end  
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. Worked like a charm. I just had to change `student.teachers << :teacher` to `student.teachers << FactoryGirl.create(:teacher)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
factory :student do
    first_name "abc"
    last_name "xyz"
end

factory :teacher do
    first_name "ABC"
    last_name "XYZ"
end

factory :institute do
    student
    teacher
end
```

Then:

```
@institute = FactoryGirl.create(:institute)
@student = @institute.student
```

This works with the validations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will give that a try too.